# The type or namespace name 'Twilio' could not be found

Tags: c#, twilio, .net-core

So I've got a dotnet core app, I'd like to use Twilio so I performed the following from the command line.

```
dotnet add package Twilio
```

All went well, no errors. It adds version 5.1.1 of Twilio packages. But building the app now gives me

```
The type or namespace name 'Twilio' could not be found
```

I'm running .Net core version 1.1 with the equivalent 1.0.1 SDK.

Any ideas?

Comment: You added Twilio to a project but not to the project that's generating the error?  Look at the project references in Visual Studio to make sure Twilio is listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you restore? The following works for me.

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Twilio
dotnet restore              <---- We need to restore after adding a package.
dotnet build
```

Program.cs

```
using Twilio;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwilioClient.SetUsername("foo");
    }
}
```

DotNetCoreTwilio.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">                         
  <PropertyGroup>                                         
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>                          
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>      
  </PropertyGroup>                                        
  <ItemGroup>                                             
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="5.1.1" /> 
  </ItemGroup>                                            
</Project>
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. First foray into .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just had this problem with a core 2.2 project. It turns out i needed an additional using statement of:

```
using Twilio.Types;
```

Visual studio wasnt providing any suggestions when it was referenced as follows:

```
twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("xx");
```

Changing the reference to the below prompted a new using suggestion from Visual Studio:

```
PhoneNumber("xx");
```

Hope this helps someone